# Angular routing to multiple outlets

Tags: angular, routes

I have an application in which I'm trying to route to multiple router outlets.  One will be the main page and one will be in a sidenav.  The routes are all working, except that nothing is appearing in the sidenav content.  The app-module routing is set up like so:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'admin', loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule)}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The primary router outlet is just the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` on a page by itself.  The admin module is set up like this:

```
const adminRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AdminComponent },
  { path: 'brands', component: BrandsComponent, outlet: 'admin_content' }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AdminComponent,
    BrandsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(adminRoutes)
  ]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

And the admin router outlet page is:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
    <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened>
        <div><button mat-icon-button (click)="showBrands()"><mat-icon fontSet="material-symbols-outlined">box_edit</mat-icon></button>Brands</div></mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content><router-outlet name="admin_content"></router-outlet></mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

The code for showBrands is:

```
  showBrands(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['admin', {outlets:{ admin_content: ['brands']}}]);
  }
```

When I click the Brands button, the brands component should show in the admin_content router outlet.  The URL changes to http://localhost:4200/admin/(admin_content:brands), but the router outlet stays blank.  What am I doing wrong here?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wxjgtb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put `<router-outlet name="admin_content"></router-outlet>` in the file `app.component.html` it works, I think it is an architecture problem because you are initializing the route with a lazy load child admin.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xvqdcq